# Invalid date for sequelize with mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query by date in sequelize with mysql, but I'm receiving invalid date.

This is the migration:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.createTable (

      'lists',
      {
        ...
        created_at: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        },
        updated_at: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE
        }

      }

    )
  },

 ...
};
```

This is the model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var List = sequelize.define("List", {

  ...

  }, {
    tableName: 'lists',
    underscored: true,
    timestamps: true,
  }

  );

  return List;
};
```

And this is how I'm trying to query it:

```
List
        .findAll(values)
        .then(function(lists) {

            console.log(lists);

            res.render('list/index.ejs', {
                lists: lists
                });
      });
```

And this is the log:

```
{ ...
       created_at: Invalid Date,
       updated_at: Invalid Date },
```

But in mysql I have dates added to it.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Try adding ```defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW``` to created_at and updated_at.

Comment: How exactly? I tried, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the `values` object in `findAll` call?